# ListBox SelectedValueChanged/SelectedIndexChanged not firing when data source changes

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, .net-4.5

I need to keep track of the selected item on a ListBox to update/disable other controls according to the currently selected value.

This is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly BindingList<string> List = new BindingList<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = List;

        listBox1.SelectedValueChanged += (s, e) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("VALUE");
        listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INDEX");

        addButton.Click += (s, e) => List.Add("Item " + (List.Count + 1));
        removeButton.Click += (s, e) => List.RemoveAt(List.Count - 1);

        logSelectionButton.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Selected Index: " + listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Selected Value: " + listBox1.SelectedValue);
        };
    }
}
```

My form has a list box `listBox1` and three buttons: `addButton`, `removeButton` and `logSelectionButton`.

If you press `addButton` (starting with an empty list), then `removeButton` and finally `addButton` again, neither `SelectedValueChanged` nor `SelectedIndexChanged` will fire at the last `addButton` press, even though if you press `logSelectionButton` before and after the last `addButton` press, you'll see that the values of both `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedValue` have changed from -1 to 0 and from `null` to "Item 1" respectively, and that "Item 1" looks selected on the list box.

This would cause any other controls I need to update according to the selected item to stay disabled until the user manually selects an item on the list box, even though the first item is already selected.

I can't think of any workaround. Perhaps also subscribing to my BindingList's `ListChanged` event to see whether the list is empty or not, but then I don't know if the items in the list box will be updated before or after my event handler fires, which will cause other problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you found a bug in `ListControl` internal handling of the [`PositionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingmanagerbase.positionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event when data bound (if you turn Exceptions on in VS, you'll see an exception when the first item is added to the empty list).

Since `ListControl` derived classes like `ListBox`, `ComboBox` etc. in data bound mode synchronize their selection with the `Position` property of the `BindingManagerBase`, the reliable workaround (and basically a more general abstract solution) is to handle [`CurrentChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingmanagerbase.currentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the underlying data source binding manager:

```
listBox1.BindingContext[List].CurrentChanged += (s, e) =>
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CURRENT");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Apparently `CurrentChanged` fires before the selection actually changes, and what I need is to keep track of the currently selected item. I found another solution (see my own response).

Comment: As you wish. I don't see why you care if control selection is changed when the same is available through `Current` property of the binding manager, and is correct. All automatic master-detail bindings and navigators use that approach rather than reacting to specific control events/properties.

Comment: Didn't know you can get the selected value from `Current`. Nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that seems to work fine. Since ListBox updates the selected index by setting the `SelectedIndex` property and the property is virtual I can override it to keep track of it:

```
public class ListBoxThatWorks : ListBox
{
    private int LatestIndex = -1;
    private object LatestValue = null;

    public EqualityComparer<object> ValueComparer { get; set; }

    public override int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return base.SelectedIndex; }
        set { SetSelectedIndex(value); }
    }

    private void NotifyIndexChanged()
    {
        if (base.SelectedIndex != LatestIndex)
        {
            LatestIndex = base.SelectedIndex;
            base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void NotifyValueChanged()
    {
        if (!(ValueComparer ?? EqualityComparer<object>.Default).Equals(LatestValue, base.SelectedValue))
        {
            LatestValue = base.SelectedValue;
            base.OnSelectedValueChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void SetSelectedIndex(int value)
    {
        base.SelectedIndex = value;
        NotifyIndexChanged();
        NotifyValueChanged();
    }
}
```