# ListBox SelectedIndexChanged event not fired when bound list updates

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'd like to have a basic ListBox with associated Add and Delete buttons.  The Delete button be enabled if and only if there is a selection in the ListBox, and the Add button should append an item to the end of the ListBox.

My first attempt was to just make a `List<string> items` field, like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1 {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.listBox1.DataSource = this.items;
    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.items.Add("item {this.items.Count + 1}");
    }

    private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.items.RemoveAt(this.listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.deleteButton.enabled = (this.listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1);
    }

    List<string> items = new List<string>();
}
```

But, it turns out that the ListBox does not seem to update automatically as the items in the list change. [Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615069/how-to-refresh-datasource-of-a-listbox-in-c-sharp-winforms) about it.

Most advice suggested just running `listBox1.DataSource = null; this.listBox1.DataSource = this.items;` every time I updated the list, but that to me defeats the purpose of **binding**.

Another answer suggested using an `ObservableCollection` for my list's data type, but that did nothing different.

Finally I found the `BindingList` class and it seemed to do what I want; the ListBox automatically reflects the contents of the `items` field. (If there is another solution that is actually a **best practice** and not some piece of cargo cult folklore pasted around the Internet, please let me know.)

---

However, when the first item I add to `items` appears in the ListBox, the row becomes selected. And I can see that `listBox1.SelectedIndex` changes from -1 to 0. But, the `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event *does not fire*. Hence, the state of the Delete button doesn't get updated properly.

(As an aside, this UI pattern is *extremely* commonplace, and it seems disastrous that there's so much conflicting information on implementing such a simple thing.)

Comment: And if I add a single item to `this.items` in the constructor, the `SelectedIndexChanged`  callback fires twice. I can't win.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem. Since this was the first question I came across, maybe my answer will save someone some time.

When `DataSource` is assigned an empty `BindingList` and items are added to that `BindingList` later, like so:

```cs
private BindingList<MyType> _myList = new BindingList<MyType>();

public MyForm()
{
    listBox1.DataSource = _myList;
}

private void LoadData()
{
    foreach (MyType item in GetDataFromSomewhere())
    {
        _myList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

then after adding the first item, that will be selected in the `ListBox`, and `listBox1.SelectedIndex` will be 0 - but the `SelectedIndexChanged` event will not have been fired.

Looks like this could be a bug in `ListBox` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42364109) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44749284).

A workaround could be to derive from `ListBox` as [Juan did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42400340), or just check if the `BindingList` contains any items before adding:

```cs
        bool isFirstItem = (0 == _myList.Count);
        _myList.Add(item);
        if (isFirstItem)
        {
            // Your choice: set listBox1.SelectedIndex to -1 and back to 0,
            // or call the event handler yourself.
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try manually selecting the last element, instead of relying on the default behavior. This will trigger the event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<string> items = new BindingList<string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.listBox1.DataSource = items;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.deleteButton.Enabled = (this.listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1);
    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.items.Add($"item {this.items.Count + 1}");
        this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = this.listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
    }

    private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.items.RemoveAt(this.listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this solution does not work. As soon as I add to `this.items`, the `SelectedIndex` is set to 0. If I then set it again to 0, no event is fired.

Comment: You're right. I was able to get it to work by setting the index to -1, then the index of the last item. See my edit. It feels like a hack, but I can't think of another way. Edit: you already tried it

Comment: In what way does it not work? The event is firing for me